# If while landing ,a surface inversion occured close to the ground would atc or atis know?

Tags: air-traffic-control, aircraft-performance, general-aviation, airport, weather

A change in temperature, pressure and many factors might happen in a surface inversion.Thus affecting landing performance and calculation.The local peessure might change suddenly as well...

Comment: Local pressure can't change suddenly. Air is a fluid and so will equalize pressure differences. The only case major pressure difference is possible is when there is very strong wind like in a storm, hurricane or tornado, and in that case you've got much bigger problem than the pressure change.

Comment: … only the pressure gradient will change a little with temperature, but you are normally ignoring that anyway; the altimeter does not have an altitude correction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably not unless a pilot reported it. METARs and TAFs only include ground temperature/pressure so presumably that's all they know.